# Windows 8(.1) additional utilities

Tags: windows-8, defragment, ccleaner

I'll be brief: 
I've formatted my computer and now I'm trying to install as little software as possible. I was wondering if CCleaner and Defraggler are really necessary?

- Is cleaning the registry really so important? And doesn't the native
- Windows 8.1 defrag tool do a proper job?

Thanks for your opinions!

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not. Both tools have an Windows implementation in the operating system. But they offer more feauteres.

For example you can clean most of the old windows files by right clicking your hard drive. Using Firefox or other browser you can delete chronices within that. CCleaner just has all in that one tool. Personally I wouldn't touch the Registry Cleaner.

Defraggler is a nice tool. I don't know what it das different from Windows Defragmentation Tool. But Defraggler offers some nice features. For example moving very large files you use only rarely to the end of the hard drive. Theoretically this can benefit perormance if smaller, more frequently used files a in the inner tracks. But if you actually "feel" the difference, I don't think so.